# Find all $n$ which $7(n^2 + n + 1)$ is perfect $4^{th}$ power.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, perfect-powers

> > Find all positive integer $n$ , which $7(n^2 + n + 1)$ is perfect $4^{th}$ power.

What I tried

Let $7(n^2 + n + 1) = a^4$ $\to$ $ 7 | a$ and $a$ is odd.

We then get $(n^2 + n + 1) = 343k^4$ ; $k \in \mathbb Z$

Hence, $ 343 | n^3 - 1$. I’m stuck here

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Ps : This problem is from my teacher , in the topic of polynomial and it’s application.

Comment: There is a solution for $k=1, n=18$, and it looks like there are no others, but I can't prove that fact

Comment: Since you mentioned polynomials, and the expression has $\Phi_3(n)$ maybe you could do something with cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: @JohnTom Sorry for asking. But, what is cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: *Hint*: Note that product of two numbers of the form $x^2+xy+y^2$ is also a number of that form, namely, $(a^2+ab+b^2)(c^2+cd+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc+bd)(ac-bd)+(ad+bc+bd)^2$.  Also $7=2^2+2+1=(-3)^2+(-3)+1$.

Comment: @IvartheBoneless read the first 2 pages of this https://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvYy84LzMxZGEwZGU0MWYzYWQ3YzQ0Njk5M2FjMTY3MzQ1YmMzYjRmMTE4&rn=Q3ljbG90b21pYyBQb2x5bm9taWFscy5wZGY=#:~:text=The%20fact%20that%20m%2Fn,gcd%2C%20so%20the%20result%20follows.&text=A%20nice%20result%20of%20cyclotomic,for%20all%20positive%20integers%20n. for an introduction.They have very nice number theoretic applications but very rarely useful. However proceed as above suggested.

Comment: $7(n^2 + n + 1) = a^4\implies (2 a^2)^2 - 7 (2 n + 1)^2 = 21$ with only $(a,n)=(7,18)$.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov: why *only*? That's the difficult part, I believe.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775552/find-all-positive-integers-n-which-1372n4-3-is-an-odd-perfect-square)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial solution. We may start by writing down the solutions of
$$ 7(n^2+n+1)=q^2 \longleftrightarrow 7(2n+1)^2-(2q)^2=-21$$
which are related (via $2n+1=m, q=7r$) to the solutions of the Pell equation
$$ m^2-7(2r)^2=-3$$
whose first solutions are given by $(m,r)\in\left\{(5,1),(37,7)\right\}$. The Pell equation $x^2-7y^2=-1$ has no solutions since $-1$ is not a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{7}$ and $x^2-7y^2=1$ has the fundamental solution $(x,y)=(8,3)$. It follows that the solutions of
$$ a^2-7b^2=-3 $$
are given by $(a,b)\in\{(2,1),(5,2),(37,14),(82,31),\ldots\}$ where the values of $a$ are given by [OEIS A202637](https://oeis.org/A202637) and the values of $b$ are given by [OEIS A202638](https://oeis.org/A202638). It follows that the values of $q$ are given by seven times the elements of the sequence [OEIS A296377](https://oeis.org/A296377)
$$ q_1=1, 7, 247, 1777, 62737, 451351, \ldots $$
fulfilling $q_n = 254 q_{n-2} - q_{n-4}$ for $n>4$. The last sequence $\!\!\pmod{7}$ has a period with length $14$ and the terms of the form $7k$ are the ones given by $q_{14s+2}$ and $q_{14s+13}$. It follows that
$$ 7(n^2+n+1)=q^2 $$
has an infinite number of non-trivial solutions, one of them being
$$ n=690845140450082,\quad q=1827804436088407 $$
and we still have to rule out the chance that (with the only exception of $q_2$) $q_{14s+2}$ or $q_{14s+13}$ is seven times a square.